# Blurry icons on Facebook and Google homepage

Tags: safari, macos, google-chrome, firefox, facebook

I am using macOS Sierra and recently I observed that the icons and images on Facebook page are all blurry on Chrome. I checked the same on Firefox and Safari and they also load all blurry icons and images.

To rule out that it's not a network issue, I connected my Ubuntu machine to the same network and the images and icons loaded just fine. No blur.

Earlier they were not blurry on Mac but I don't know what changed. I tried clearing cache and also removed Chrome and reinstalled but got the same issue. What could be the reason for this behavior?

Attaching a screenshot below -

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot so we can all see what you mean by "blurry".

Comment: @Little.Eden I have added screenshot of the blurry icons.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Tested in 4 different browsers and all of them the blur occurs. In Chrome I was able to temporarily remove the blur by closing a tab and reopening it with `cmd-shit-t`

Comment: @Otávio Yes, I tried closing the tab and then opened it pressing `cmd + shift + t`. The blur goes away but as soon as I reload the page by pressing `cmd + r`, it's back to blurry icons. Can't understand why is this happening.